# Rails + Capybara: How to target last div of a certain class?

Tags: capybara

I have 3 divs with class `variant_container`. How would I select the last one so that I could do

```
within(last_variant_div) do
   ...
end
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your preferences, here are two solutions.

**Using XPath**

XPath has a `last()` function to find the last matching node. You can use this in the within locator:

```
within(:xpath, '(//div[@class="variant_container"])[last()]') do
  # do stuff
end
```

**Using all**

The `within` method can also be passed a node to search within. This means that you can locate the last node by `find` or `all`, which can sometimes give more flexibility.

For example, in this case, we can now use a CSS-selector to find the last div (by combining it with Capybara's `all` method). Note that CSS-selectors by themselves do not have the ability to find the last element of a certain class.

```
last_div = all('div.variant_container').last
within(last_div) do
  # do stuff
end
```